# NHibernate shards

Tags: nhibernate, sharding

I saw today Ayende's article about NH shards here http://ayende.com/blog/4252/nhibernate-shards-progress-report. First time I heard that NH supports sharding and I couldn't find any useful info/tips about. So I wanted to know the progress, is it stable? How it handles transactions/acid properties? Does it support all databases supported by NH or not? 
Any information would be welcome :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working with NH Shards and I can say that it works well. In fact, there is not so many information and examples available on the Internet. As far I know, it supports all databases by NH. But it has some limitations and some functions are not totally implemented.

It works well with Fluent NHibernate API.
Most of the documentation that you can find is available from the Java JBoss Hibernate Shards project. The idea is the same, considering that NH Shards came from HShards.

Here are some useful links:

NH Shards temporary host: http://code.google.com/p/nhshards/source/list

Multitenant Database using Shards: http://weblog4j.com/2011/09/09/multitenant-database-using-hibernate-shards/

Comment: second link is broken

Comment: The Hibernate shards documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/shards/reference/en/html_single/ gives an idea of possibilities and limitations.

Comment: [NH Shards code base](https://github.com/darioquintana/NHibernate-Shards) is on GitHub since some time now.